Access API Gateway Interface Endpoint from ALB
I have an API gateway deployed with a private endpoint configuration, the endpoint configuration consists of an interface endpoint with the service name "com.amazonaws.af-south-1.execute-api" that is attached to my private subnets. The API Gateway allows me to access a backend ec2 instance running a basic flask application that I use for testing.
I deployed an internal application load balancer to forward requests to my API Gateway using the interface endpoint, I did this by configuring a target group for my load balancer to forward requests to the private IP of the ENI attached to the interface endpoint. For testing, the load balancer accepts traffic on port 80 from 0.0.0.0/0 and the endpoint's security group is open on all ports for 0.0.0.0/0
Prior to deploying my load balancer, this is how tested access to my API gateway through the interface endpoint:
curl -X POST https://{rest-api-id}-{vpce-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{stage}/{path}
Note: I have a test ec2 instance in the same private subnet as my flask instance that I use for running these curl commands
My question is, how do I now access the API Gateway through the application load balancer? I tried using the same curl command against the DNS name of my load balancer like this, but with no luck:
curl -X POST https://{load-balancer-dns-name}/{stage}/{path}
Ultimately, I am trying to configure my application load balancer to handle mutual tls requests for my API Gateway, here is an article for reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/consuming-private-amazon-api-gateway-apis-using-mutual-tls/
